# Adding custom gitlab repository in build.sbt

Tags: scala, gitlab, sbt

how can i add custom gitlab repository to my build.sbt file? i was able to add a repository without authentication like this:

```
resolvers ++= Seq(
  "custom" at ""
)
```

but i don't know how to add private token into request header. for instance, you can do it like this in gradle:

```
maven {
    url "https://
    name "GitLab"
    credentials(HttpHeaderCredentials) {
        name = 'Private-Token'
        value = ''
    }
    authentication {
        header(HttpHeaderAuthentication)
    }
}
```

Comment: Not really in your `build.sbt`, but does this help? https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Proxy-Repositories.html

Comment: Credentials should not be in the build.sbt. They would be too easy to leak

Comment: @GaëlJ yes, it's obvious that i'm not trying to put any credentials. i just want to know how to add authentication